# Цикл javascript

Tags: jquery, javascript

Как сделать такое, циклом

```
    var test1 = $('#m1 li img');
    test1.hide();

    var test2 = $('#m2 li img');
    test2.hide();

    var test3 = $('#m3 li img');
    test3.hide();

    var test4 = $('#m4 li img');
    test4.hide();
```

Спасибо!

Comment: Быть может стоит обозначить эти элементы общим классом и изменять так:  

    $("#some_class").hide();

Comment: нет, данные код сделал для примера, в реале совсем другая картина

Comment: .
    $(".some-class").hide();

Comment: >нет, данные код сделал для примера, в реале совсем другая картина

и чем ваша другая картина отличается?

Comment: там больше переменный и они очень часто потребляются

Comment: так чем для вашего "больше переменный" не подходит назначение общего класса?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Может так вот?

```
var selectors = ['m1', 'm2', 'm3'],
    len = selectors.length,
    elm;    
while(len--) {
    elm = $( selectors[len] + ' li img');
    elm.hide();
    // $( selectors[len] + ' li img').hide();
}
```

Или давайте реальный пример в студию.

Comment: а ладно пусть будет так

Comment: А чем ответ предыдущего товарища не угодил?

Comment: а я его не минусовал и не удалял :), мне не его, не твой код, не подошел, просто я решил $('#slector') не объявлять отдельную переменную, а использовать его несколько раз